# Shell script getopts weird behaviour args not parsing

Tags: shell-script, parameter, getopts

I'm trying a simple shell script to get the arguments passed by the user, but cannot seem to find my error. Sometimes it works, but mostly not (weird).

```
helpFunc()
{
        echo ""
        echo "Usage: cdcode [-w] [-f paramF] [-h]"
        echo -e "\t-w for WebDev folder"
        echo -e "\t-f Specify a custom folder to concat at the end to CD into"
        echo -e "\t-h Display help"
        echo
}
while getopts "a:b:c:" opt
do
   case "$opt" in
       a ) paramA="$OPTARG" ;;
       b ) paramB="$OPTARG" ;;
       c ) paramC="$OPTARG" ;;
       ? ) helpFunc ;; # Print helpFunc in case parameter is non-existent
   esac
done
echo $paramA
echo $paramB
echo $paramC
```

**RUN**

```
$ cdcode -a aaa -b bbbb -c cccc
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$
$
$
```

I get three empty lines, as my variables `paramA, paramB, paramC` have not been initialized.

Comment: 'Mostly doesn't work': are you running it always on the same computer? Or it doesn't work on different computers with maybe different versions of bash? What versions of bash? Or are you using a different shell? I can confirm the script works fine every time on bash 5.0

Comment: I'm running 4.4.23 and always in the same computer. I'll upgrade and try again.

Comment: What shell are you using interactively? Where's your first line `#!` marker in the script to tell the shell what interpreter to use? Are you sure that, if the script is `cdcode`, you're actually running the correct version?

Comment: "_I get three empty lines_" I don't see empty lines in your output; I see three lines consisting of a dollar symbol (`$`). Which is correct?

Comment: I figured it out, I was trying to pass arguments to an alias without a function. Rookie mistake. Thanks for your time!